# razor @Html.TextBoxFor using type="url" instead of default type="text"

Tags: razor

How can I do razor's `@Html.TextBoxFor(...)`, but, have the type render to type="url" vs. type="text" ?  Do I need to build an extension, or, just wait for next version of MVC or C#, which will hopefully have something like `@Html.UrlBoxFor(...)` ?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Orchard 1.6 which uses MVC 4. In this version of MVC you can specify the type with the htmlAttributes parameter.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Url, new{@class = "text-box textMedium", type = "url"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the 'type=url' attribute, and it will overwrite the 'type=text' attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Url, new { @type = "url" })
```